# Identifying a font and using it

Tags: fonts

I have been trying to figure out what these 3 fonts are named for quite a while now and I have been having no success. I did get some help from one of my friends that said the first one was ccr and the last one was cmss. But when I tried searching for them online and trying to use them myself I couldn't do that either. I am a beginner at LaTeX.

```
\usepackage{concmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

On a guide online it told me to use these, but that made the default text a different font, how would I change the font of a specific block of text?

[image: http://imgur.com/vv7NXSf]

Comment: Welcome! What are 'these 3 fonts'? Can you please give us a complete example rather than a snippet? We should be able to compile it to reproduce your situation.

Comment: Where are the fonts from? You can identify fonts in a PDF by looking at 'Properties' in your viewer or using `pdffonts`. I'm not clear whether you are trying to change font shape (e.g. for small-caps) or whether you are trying to change to sans/typewriter or whether you are trying to use non-default fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want to use sans/typewriter/serif small-caps etc.?

[image: variations]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% not required but recommended
\begin{document}
  You are going

  \texttt{You are going}

  \textsc{You are going}

  \textsf{You are going}
\end{document}
```